# twitter bootstrap button group with transparent background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group using twitter bootstrap as you see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmk7H/

It makes a linear-gradient background:

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6)
```

which is annoying me. I want it to have a transparent background by adding `mynav` class. How should I modify `mynav` class?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group mynav">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
Username
<span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="nav-header">List header</li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  ...
  </ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mynav
{

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make the background of the `a` transparent add this

```
.mynav > a {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmk7H/2/

Answer (score 2):

Transparant, like this?

```
.mynav .btn
{
    background-image: none;
}
```